# Generate an array of numbers from a number and a mask of bits in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary, numbers

I would like to create a function that returns an array (or vector) of numbers from a bit mask, my function header would be:

```
vector generateArray(int number, int maskSize)
```

if I call this function this way:

```
generateArray(4,2)
```

4 being equal to 100 in binary,

it would return a vector with these numbers: 5 , 6 , 7 which are in binary 101,110 and 111. So the function changed all the 2 last bits of the number 100 to generate all the possibilities.

I have no clue how to do it .. any idea would help a lot !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick -

```
void generateArray(int n, int m) {
    if (m == 0) {
        printf ("%d\n", n);
        return;
    }
    int mask = 1 << (m-1);
    generateArray(n & ~mask, m-1);
    generateArray(n |  mask, m-1);
}
```

This c code prints out the numbers, but the principle is the same - just modify it to accumulate them in your vector, and remove the initial parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Your mask size can be thought of as a way to generate all numbers that can be represented using `maskSize` bits. In your example that is `2` or 2 bits, which has 2<sup>2</sup> possible values: 00 01 10 11, or 0, 1, 2, 3, which if you add each of those to `number` gives you 4, 5, 6, and 7.

So what you do is compute all the numbers that can be reached from 2<sup>maskSize</sup> and add those to `number' to fill out your array.